# how to extract only the path from askopenfile method

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
def get_fileLocation(): 
    file = askopenfile(mode ='r', filetypes =[('excel file','*.xlsx')]) 
    if file is not None:  
        print("printing conter",file)
```

I tried this to get the path of a file. But the result I received is raw like this `<_io.TextIOWrapper name='D:/my projects/Seating Allotement/UI corrections/classes.xlsx' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>` and how to split only the path something like `'D:/my projects/Seating Allotement/UI corrections/classes.xlsx'`  this? or are there some other way to get the path

Comment: Are you aware that there's an `askopenfilename` method?

Comment: Use `file.name` to get the filename or use `askopenfilename()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to look at these functions :

```
self.selected_file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(
                                        title="Select file", filetypes=(("csv files", "*.csv"),))

just_the_filename = os.path.basename(self.selected_file_path)

just_the_dirname = os.path.dirname(self.selected_file_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use file.name method to get the file name with directory.

```
def get_fileLocation(): 
    file = askopenfile(mode ='r', filetypes =[('excel file','*.xlsx')]) 
    f_dir = file.name
    if file is not None:  
        print("printing conter",f_dir)
```

if you want only file name without the directory(i.e. only classes.xlsx) try this:

```
import os
def get_fileLocation(): 
    file = askopenfile(mode ='r', filetypes =[('excel file','*.xlsx')]) 
    f_dir = file.name
    f_name = os.path.basename(f_dir)
    if file is not None:  
        print("printing conter",f_name)
```

If you want to remove the extension add this in code:

```
os.path.splitext(f_dir)[0]

output: 'D:/my projects/Seating Allotement/UI corrections/classes'

OR

os.path.splitext(f_name)[0]

Output: classes
```